# Pass multiple model to controller in ActionResult Create

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, actionresult

I have create four models, then i have created a viewmodel that contains first four, i have created a view with controller that show this viewmodel;

When i created Actioresult Create (http post), i on't know how pass entire model.

viewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Avvisi.Models
{
public class PianoCompletoViewModels
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public DatiPiano DatiPiano { get; set; }
public DescrizionePiano descrizionePiano { get; set; }
public ImpresaBeneficiaria impresaBeneficiaria { get; set; }
public ResponsabilePiano responsabilePiano { get; set; }
public ProspettoFinanziario prospettoFinanziario { get;set; }
}
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
   {
string UserID = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.GetUserId());
int AvvisoID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["AvvisoID"]);
ViewBag.FKCompartoID = new SelectList(db.Comparto, "CompartoID", 
"Nome");
 ViewBag.PianoID = new SelectList(db.DescrizionePiano, 
"DescrizioneID", "PresentImpBenef_RelContAziend");
 return View();
 }
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PianoCompletoViewController PianoView)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View();
}
return View();
}
```

I expect that when i click on submit there is a model filled wiht property(other mmodels) For Example:

```
PianoView.model1.xxx
PianoView.model2.xxx
PianoView.model3.xxx
PianoView.model4.xxx
```

cshtml view:

```
@model Avvisi.Models.PianoCompletoViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Dati Piano</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Dati Piano</h4>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="row" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatiPiano.NomePiano, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatiPiano.NomePiano, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatiPiano.NomePiano, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descrizionePiano.PresentImpBenef_RelContAziend, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descrizionePiano.PresentImpBenef_RelContAziend, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descrizionePiano.PresentImpBenef_RelContAziend, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.impresaBeneficiaria.CompanyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.impresaBeneficiaria.CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.impresaBeneficiaria.CompanyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.responsabilePiano.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.responsabilePiano.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.responsabilePiano.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" style="width:95%;background: #dedede;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I don't understand why it no let me to choose right properties(Models).

Can you help me, please???

Answer (score 0):

You have to use html control name like this:

```
<input name="descrizionePiano.someProperty">
```

Then surely you have got value for it.

Comment: No problem doesn't in html, i have updated my main post; Problem is in submit "event" when httpost is fired for the create view, i'd want pass my view model, but i cannot access its property. if i write  public ActionResult Create (PianoCompletoViewController pianoView) i expect that pianoview contains property of model, in this case i'd want pianoview.datipiano, pianoview.descrizionepiano etc... but when i write pianoview after dot notation there isn't properties.